# use underscore or lodash convert one JSON structure to another

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have a problem trying to convert current JSON structure to another

```
var data = [
  {
    "url": "asset/01.flv",
    "pic": "asset/01.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/02.flv",
    "pic": "asset/02.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/03.flv",
    "pic": "asset/03.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/04.flv|asset/05.flv|asset/06.flv|asset/07.flv|asset/08.flv",
    "pic": "asset/04.jpg|asset/05.jpg|asset/06.jpg|asset/07.jpg|asset/08.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/09.flv|asset/10.flv",
    "pic": "asset/09.jpg|asset/10.jpg"
  }
]
```

I want to convert data to an output structure like this.
Here's the target with just the result I want to achieve.

```
var data = [
  {
    "url": "asset/01.flv",
    "pic": "asset/01.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/02.flv",
    "pic": "asset/02.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/03.flv",
    "pic": "asset/03.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/04.flv",
    "pic": "asset/04.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/05.flv",
    "pic": "asset/05.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/06.flv",
    "pic": "asset/06.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/07.flv",
    "pic": "asset/07.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/08.flv",
    "pic": "asset/08.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/09.flv",
    "pic": "asset/09.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/10.flv",
    "pic": "asset/10.jpg"
  }
]
```

It is diffcult for me, could someone help me in this matter? I've tried for several hours. Using lodash or underscore or plain JS is ok. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the use of `Array#reduce`. The idea is to loop over the array and check if the `url` and `pic` has `|` in their values.

If so, split the value and push all items to the result. If not, push the `url` and `pic` as it is.

```js
var data = [{"url":"asset/01.flv","pic":"asset/01.jpg"},{"url":"asset/02.flv","pic":"asset/02.jpg"},{"url":"asset/03.flv","pic":"asset/03.jpg"},{"url":"asset/04.flv|asset/05.flv|asset/06.flv|asset/07.flv|asset/08.flv","pic":"asset/04.jpg|asset/05.jpg|asset/06.jpg|asset/07.jpg|asset/08.jpg"},{"url":"asset/09.flv|asset/10.flv","pic":"asset/09.jpg|asset/10.jpg"}];

var result = data.reduce((r, {url, pic}) => {
  if (url.includes('|') && pic.includes('|')) {
    var urls = url.split('|');
    var pics = pic.split('|');
    
    urls.forEach((u, i) => {
      r.push({url: u, pic: pics[i]});
    });
  } else {
    r.push({url, pic})
  }
  
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use of an `Array.reduce` to do the manipulation yourself.

```js
const arr = [{
    "url": "asset/01.flv",
    "pic": "asset/01.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/02.flv",
    "pic": "asset/02.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/03.flv",
    "pic": "asset/03.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/04.flv|asset/05.flv|asset/06.flv|asset/07.flv|asset/08.flv",
    "pic": "asset/04.jpg|asset/05.jpg|asset/06.jpg|asset/07.jpg|asset/08.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/09.flv|asset/10.flv",
    "pic": "asset/09.jpg|asset/10.jpg"
  }
];

console.log(arr.reduce((tmp, {
  pic,
  url,
}) => {
  const urlSplit = url.split('|');

  return [
    ...tmp,

    ...pic.split('|').map((x, xi) => ({
      pic: x,
      url: urlSplit[xi],
    })),
  ];
}, []));
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you can do something like this using [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var data = [{"url":"asset/01.flv","pic":"asset/01.jpg"},{"url":"asset/02.flv","pic":"asset/02.jpg"},{"url":"asset/03.flv","pic":"asset/03.jpg"},{"url":"asset/04.flv|asset/05.flv|asset/06.flv|asset/07.flv|asset/08.flv","pic":"asset/04.jpg|asset/05.jpg|asset/06.jpg|asset/07.jpg|asset/08.jpg"},{"url":"asset/09.flv|asset/10.flv","pic":"asset/09.jpg|asset/10.jpg"}];

var parsedData = data.reduce((accumulator, e) => {
  e['url'].split('|').forEach((ele, i) => {
    accumulator.push({"url":ele, "pic": e['pic'].split('|')[i]})
  })
  return accumulator;
}, [])

console.log(parsedData);
```

Same solution using [Underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js)'s [`_.zip()`](https://underscorejs.org/#zip) function.

```js
var data = [{"url":"asset/01.flv","pic":"asset/01.jpg"},{"url":"asset/02.flv","pic":"asset/02.jpg"},{"url":"asset/03.flv","pic":"asset/03.jpg"},{"url":"asset/04.flv|asset/05.flv|asset/06.flv|asset/07.flv|asset/08.flv","pic":"asset/04.jpg|asset/05.jpg|asset/06.jpg|asset/07.jpg|asset/08.jpg"},{"url":"asset/09.flv|asset/10.flv","pic":"asset/09.jpg|asset/10.jpg"}];

var parsedData = data.reduce((accumulator, e) => {
  return accumulator.concat(...(_.zip(e['url'].split('|'), e['pic']
             .split('|'))
             .map(([url, pic]) => ({url, pic}))))
}, []);

console.log(parsedData)
```

```html
<script src="https://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Check `flatMap`, `reduce` should be the last resort when no other higher level abstractions work.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply use a `flatmap` with `zipWith`??

```
const sortedData = _.flatMap(data, obj =>
    _.zipWith(
        obj.url.split("|"),
        obj.pic.split("|"),
        (url, pic) => ({url, pic})
    )
);
```

```js
var data = [
  {
    "url": "asset/01.flv",
    "pic": "asset/01.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/02.flv",
    "pic": "asset/02.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/03.flv",
    "pic": "asset/03.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/04.flv|asset/05.flv|asset/06.flv|asset/07.flv|asset/08.flv",
    "pic": "asset/04.jpg|asset/05.jpg|asset/06.jpg|asset/07.jpg|asset/08.jpg"
  },
  {
    "url": "asset/09.flv|asset/10.flv",
    "pic": "asset/09.jpg|asset/10.jpg"
  }
]

var res = _.flatMap(data, o=>_.zipWith(o.url.split("|"), o.pic.split("|"), (url, pic) => ({url, pic})));

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think this is the most elegant approach. Maybe you can use a proper code block and fix the indention? as a single line is hard to grasp.

Comment: Hey thanks @tokland, basically I haven't formatted because I have used only 2 functions *flatMap* and *zipWith* and just performed a much necessary *split*. I have tried a formatter after you suggested, which was breaking it to another line just with the final return statement *({url, pic})*. You can edit if you feel some formatting of that line suits more for better understanding, that will be helpful to others :)

Comment: Done! Feel free to revert it if you don't like so many line breaks ;)